# Are method calls in optional condition branches executed

Tags: abap

Say we have a condition `IF foo( ) OR bar( ).` and `foo( )` returns `abap_true`, will `bar( )` be called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, according to the [abap documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenlogexp_boole.htm), parts of the condition are only executed when the corresponding logic branch is evaluated

> *The logical expressions of a parenthesis level are processed from left to right. If the value of a logical expression determines the total value of the parenthesis level, the remaining logical expressions are no longer evaluated. In particular, the dynamic parts of the expressions that are not evaluated, such as field symbols or reference variables, are not checked for validity.*